# Web Api and OAuth authentication with multiple clients and users

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

We are a developing an AngularJS single page application with an ASP.NET Web Api 2 REST API.  We are using OWIN middleware and OAuth, but are still unsure if we are taking the correct approach.

Our system consists of clients and users:

- **Clients** are organisations/companies.
- **Users** are employees of those companies.  Users belong to a client.

## Getting a bearer token with a clientId:

[image: Bearer Token]

**Should we be returning the `clientId` at this point?**

The AngularJS front-end layer does need this `clientId` to perform other resource calls.  For example:

- `api/clients/2345/orders`
- `api/clients/2345/orders/522`
- `api/clients/2345/departments`

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with companies, the active directory approach to SPAs (and Angular specifically) might be a good fit: you can use http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ as a starting point. The token acquisition and use are fully abstracted there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we aren't able to integrate with AD at this point.